# Is it okay that rollback journal stores maximum 1 KB and autocommit queries tho transcation is not commited yet?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I use Sqlite3Wrapper in my project and I noticed a strange behavior: I begin transaction and execute a lot of queries, one by one. The problem I face is that journal stores maximum 1KB of data before it auto commits. This process repeats until all data is saved to database. Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: What do you mean with "auto commits"? If there really were a commit, your explicit commit would fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling `BEGIN`, nothing will be commited until you either call `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`

> Any command that changes the database (basically, any SQL command other than SELECT) will automatically start a transaction if one is not already in effect. Automatically started transactions are committed when the last query finishes.
>
> Transactions can be started manually using the BEGIN command. **Such transactions usually persist until the next COMMIT or ROLLBACK command.**

If you don't use `BEGIN`, you will by default be operating in autocommit mode. You can check this via [`sqlite3_get_autocommit`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html).

> Autocommit mode is on by default. Autocommit mode is disabled by a BEGIN statement. Autocommit mode is re-enabled by a COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

Comment: The thing is there is only 2 member functions of my db saver that are related to transactions: CommitTranscation and BeginTransaction. Both of them use db adapter like that: "m_dataBase->execDML("begin transaction");". I put breakpoints inside them but I had no success. However, I can see lots of transactions -- https://embed.gyazo.com/a183859f5e65d6d97c2e289f90cda315.gif